# How do I get a list of available fonts to select from in the TextField component?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In textfield component ,there's a class named `TextFormat`.  TextFormat has a property named `font` which can let you set the font, but the help document doesn't give any information about the font, it only tells you the default was "Times New Roman", so I can only set 'Times New Roman'?

Is there a way to list all the fonts available so I can pick up one from the list?

Comment: Related: http://blog.erikphansen.com/actionscript-textformatfont-values/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at `Font.enumerateFonts()` this function will give you a list of all available embedded and device fonts.

[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#enumerateFonts()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/Font.html#enumerateFonts%28%29)

> This example first calls the static method Font.enumerateFonts() to
>   get a list of all device and embedded fonts. Then it sorts the
>   resulting Array of Font objects by the fontName property.
>
> Next the example shows how to call the Font.enumerateFonts() method
>   with the enumerateDeviceFonts parameter set to false. The resulting
>   Array only includes embedded Font objects. (If you run this code
>   within an application that does not contain any embedded fonts, the
>   embeddedFonts array will be empty.)

```
import flash.text.Font;

var allFonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(true);
allFonts.sortOn("fontName", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);

var embeddedFonts:Array = Font.enumerateFonts(false);
embeddedFonts.sortOn("fontName", Array.CASEINSENSITIVE);
```